# Google Maps JS API with KML layer control

Tags: google-maps, dynamic, google-maps-api-3, kml, layer

I have found different solutions for switching KmlLayers on/off using JavaScript. All scripts that I've seen require separate functions for each layer, but I want to have only one function for all layers so when adding a new layer to my web page I don't have to edit the existing JavaScript code.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<style type="text/css">
    * {margin:0; padding:0; border:0; outline:0; font-size:100%; 
        vertical-align:baseline}
    html, body {width:100%; height:100%}
    #map {width:100%; height:95%}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=lv">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var G = google.maps; var kml = null; var show = false;

    function toggle() {
        var tr = this.rel;
        if (!tr) {
            tr = new G.KmlLayer('http://www.eiranet.lv/kartes/Anjo/kmz/' +
                this.id + '.kmz', {preserveViewport:true})
        };
        show = !show;
        if (show) {
            tr.setMap(map)
        }
        else {
            tr.setMap(null)
        };
    };

    function initialize() {
        var layers = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var options = {
            center: new G.LatLng(34.9, 137.3),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: G.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
            scaleControl: true,
            overviewMapControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style:G.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU }
        };

        map = new G.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

        for (var i=0; i<layers.length; i++) {
            layers[i].type = 'checkbox';
            G.event.addDomListener(layers[i], 'click', toggle)
        };
    };

    G.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<input id="Didzis_21.03-03.04" rel="d1"/>
<input id="Didzis_04.04-17.04" rel="d2"/>
<input id="Didzis_18.04-01.05" rel="d3"/>
<input id="Didzis_02.05-15.05" rel="d4"/>
</body></html>
```

Here is my problem: actually I can switch multiple layers on but I can't turn them off. I think that all of the code is good except function `toggle()`. Also, it would be good if 'rel' attributes wouldn't be necessary, only 'id'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like each `KmlLayer` that you create gets orphaned; they are assigned to a function local `var` named `tr`, but then never assigned to anything that will remain available across multiple calls to `toggle()`. I suggest some changes to the `toggle()` function:

```
function toggle() {
    if (!this.kmlLayer ) {
        this.kmlLayer = new G.KmlLayer(
            'http://www.eiranet.lv/kartes/Anjo/kmz/' + this.id + '.kmz',
            { preserveViewport:true } );
    }
    show = !show;
    if (show) {
        this.kmlLayer.setMap(map)
    }
    else {
        this.kmlLayer.setMap(null)
    };
};
```

After reviewing your page in some more detail, I suggest additional changes:

```
function toggle() {
    if (!this.kmlLayer ) {
        this.kmlLayer = new G.KmlLayer(
            'http://www.eiranet.lv/kartes/Anjo/kmz/' + this.id + '.kmz',
            { preserveViewport:true } );
        this.displayIsOn = false;
    }
    //show = !show;  --  Remove this line, it is causing display state problems
    if ( this.displayIsOn ) {
        this.kmlLayer.setMap( null );
        this.displayIsOn = false;
    }
    else {
        this.kmlLayer.setMap( map );
        this.displayIsOn = true;
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Now it works better, it's possible to turn on and off single layers but manipulating with multiple layers remains tricky. You can test this page here:http://www.eiranet.lv/kartes/Anjo/kmz/karte.html

Comment: Made some changes, after reviewing your page. See code above.

Comment: Perfect :) I also found about geoxml3 http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/ with this script you can use overlays directly from a pc, not sending them to Google so it gives better performance.