# Multi Kml Layer on Google maps

Tags: maps, kml, layer

I have developed a simple google map web page.  I need help form anyone who has experience in google maps.  In right panel of my web page I add some checkboxes and I want to link different kml with these checkboxes.  When I check all layer all kml are show in google maps and when I uncheck any layer checkbox then kml related to that checkbox will disappear. Please guide me how I can do this. 
Please check the page from this link
http://toptrippk.com/webgis/kml%20layers.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following structure. Using this method you don't have to write seperate functions for every layer but only this one. Note that 'id' of 'input' tags here is used as KML filename. You probably want to see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563233/google-maps-js-api-with-kml-layer-control). If looking forward then [geoxml3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621618/geoxml3-google-maps-with-kml-layer-control) may be an option for you.

```
var G = google.maps;
function toggle() {
if (!this.kml)
{this.kml = new G.KmlLayer('http://toptrippk.com/webgis/uploadfiles/kml/' + this.id + '.kml', {preserveViewport:true}); this.on = false};

if (this.on)
{this.kml.setMap(null); this.on = false} else {this.kml.setMap(map); this.on = true};
};

function initialize() {
var layers = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var options = {};
map = new G.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);
for (var i=0; i<layers.length; i++) {G.event.addDomListener(layers[i], 'click', toggle)};};
G.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```