# geoxml3 - Google Maps with KML layer control

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, controls, kml, layer

I'm using geoxml3 to display KML files on Google Maps. I made script with which different KML layers can be turned on and off. Although every layer turns on as expected, when trying to turn off one layer, turns off another.

```js
var G = google.maps;
var layers = new function() {this.data = [
{id:'japan',url:'kvadrati.kml'},
{id:'d1',   url:'Didzis_21.03-03.04.kml'},
{id:'d2',   url:'Didzis_04.04-17.04.kml'},
... ]};

function toggle() {for (var i=0; i<layers.data.length; i++) {
if (this.id == layers.data[i].id) {
if (layers.data[i].parsed) {
if (layers.data[i].on)
{geo.hideDocument(geo.docs[i]); layers.data[i].on = false}
else {geo.showDocument(geo.docs[i]); layers.data[i].on = true}}
else {geo.parse(layers.data[i].url); layers.data[i].parsed = true; layers.data[i].on = true}}
};};

function initialize() {
var options = {
   center:new G.LatLng(34.9, 137.3), 
   zoom:10, 
   mapTypeId:G.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, 
   scaleControl:true, 
   overviewMapControl:true, 
   mapTypeControlOptions:{style:G.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
};
map = new G.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
geo = new geoXML3.parser({
             map:map, 
             zoom:false, 
             singleInfoWindow:true, 
             infoWindowOptions:{maxWidth:100}, 
             processStyles:true, 
             markerOptions:{shadow:''}
      });
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i=0; i<el.length; i++) {
    el[i].type = 'checkbox'; 
    G.event.addDomListener(el[i], 'click', toggle)};
};
G.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I'm sure that problem is in function toggle() where appears:

```js
geo.[show/hide]Document(geo.docs[i]);
```

[Test it here](http://www.eiranet.lv/kartes/Anjo/map/).
It takes quite a long time to load a layer because they are in uncompressed (KML) format. I read that geoxml3 should support [KMZ files](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_multiple.html), I even copied every file from this example but it wasn't working for me. Anybody knows why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the right code where function toggle() is:

```
function toggle() {
for (var i=0; i<layers.length; i++) {
var x = layers[i];
var xurl = './layers/' + x.url;
if (this.id == x.id)
{if (x.render)
{for (var n=0; n<geo.docs.length; n++)
{var y = geo.docs[n];
if (y.url == xurl)
{if (x.on) {geo.hideDocument(y); x.on = false} else {geo.showDocument(y); x.on = true}}
}}
else {geo.parse(xurl); x.render = true; x.on = true}}}};
```

Quite crazy function, many if statements but I guess it can't be any simpler or cleaner than this.

**EDIT:**

```
function toggle() {var x = this;
if (x.r) {(x.on) ? geo.hideDocument(geo.docs[x.n]) : geo.showDocument(geo.docs[x.n])}
else {geo.parse(x.href); x.r = true; x.n = geo.docs.length}; x.on = !x.on};
```

Removed layers array as it wasn't necessary, now I'm using href from anchor tags to parse a layer, not clicking input but a elements. So the script turned out really short.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with the `geo.showDocument`, the argument you are passing (`geo.docs` is not indiced in the same way as your layers.data array, and you can't have a rational result that way.
You should find another way to tell geoxml3 which document to hide, based for example on the url property of each cell of the geo.docs array, which will more consistently match the layers.data array.

For the KMZ parsing question, you need to use another branch of the geoxml3 library, checking out with svn this address: http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/kmz . It is still in development, so bugs are not excluded.

Comment: Have you tried to parse KMZ with geoxml3? I can't get a working page with KMZ rendering at all. If only there would be some downloadable examples like archives to be sure that it's really working.

Comment: Nope I did not, I am only using the polys branch. It seems that the main functions are not really different, the geoxml3.js file takes care of determining if the url passed corresponds to a zip file.